# Comando (RUN) sumiu e não atende ao ctrl + enter

Tags: comandos

Boa tarde! Meu comando (RUN) sumiu.
Não está carregando nada, nem com crtl + enter...
Já desinstalei e instalei novamente, alguém e que pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Ontem eu estava rodando umas análises no R e após verificar o plot, percebi que o botão RUN não estava mais disponível. Então, eu tentei algumas possibilidades, mas sem sucesso.